# Average of last 5 values using averageifs

Tags: microsoft-excel

How to calculate the average of last 5 values with many other criteria for averageifs.

I only was able to calculate the average meeting all other criteria except the last 5 values.

Here is the google spread sheet for the [sample data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zJAukF6CtDEJnL93SiE7SobhqNbMbqsG35TndPkIUWg/)

for example, 2016/06/01 is the date I am looking at, then from the table I need average of values for last 5 available dates after all the criteria met. Please look at the google sheet again and check the table in blue. That needs to be calculated for given date, another_no and abc.

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If an answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey ☑ to the left of the text, which means "yes, this is THE answer"!

Comment: Can you define "last 5" that's the latest (timewise) 5 in the month in question? What if there are fewer than 5 that meet the criteria? - it would be good to see some expected results

Comment: @barryhoudini for example, 2016/06/01 is the date I am looking at, then from the table I need average of values for last 5 available dates after all the criteria met. Please look at the google sheet again and check the table in blue. That needs to be calculated for given date, another_no and abc
Thanks!

Comment: @Hannu I will surely do If that is the answer. Thanks

Comment: I've Solved your problem on attached data sheet, there you can check it, only in one Column Formula reflecting results since your Criteria is not matching with Data Source at the Right. Check and Reply.

Comment: @RajeshS The average value should of previous 5 dates available  after meeting all the other criteria.

Comment: If considering 5 days back only one date is matching in Column 1 for 1,2 & 5, check the sheet.

Comment: @Rajesh, your edits to OP's spreadsheet are not a correct answer to his question.  See my answer below and try to identify why/what you misunderstood.  In the future, it would be wonderful if you would make certain that you really understand the question before you post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This formula in B2, filled down and across, will do what you're asking.

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS($J$4:$J$90,$H$4:$H$90,"<="&B$1,$H$4:$H$90,">="&B$1-5,$I$4:$I$90,$C$8,$K$4:$K$90,$A2),"")
```

It averages those cells where

1. The date is less than or equal to the date in Row 1, and greater
   than or equal to 5 days prior to that date.
2. another_no is equal to the value in Column A.
3. abc is equal to the value in C8.

The IFERROR() wrapper returns a blank where AVERAGEIFS() would give a #DIV/0! error. Some result cells are blank because there are no values to average that meet the criteria.  The count of the cells matching the criteria is shown in the second table.

[image]